# Restify: "override" default next

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I want to kinda override default next in Restify. E.g. now i have code like

```
server.post('/names', function (req, res, next) {
  names = req.params.names;
  if (!Array.isArray(names)) {
    return next(new restify.errors.BadRequestError('names field is wrong or missing'));
  }
  res.send({ code: "OK" });
  return next();
});
```

I want it to be just

```
server.post('/names', function (req, res, next) {
  names = req.params.names;
  if (!Array.isArray(names)) {
    return next(new restify.errors.BadRequestError('names field is wrong or missing'));
  }
  // Add names to DB
  return next();
});
```

Where `next` (for non-error results) is like

```
function next(res) {
  if (!body.hasOwnProperty("code")) {
    body["code"] = "OK";
  }
  res.send(body);
}
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Your code is missing `var` keywords on every variable declaration. This is bad because without `var` everything becomes global. Double-check your code, every variable declaration without `var` is a bug waiting to happen. Tools like [jshint](http://jshint.com/) help find these mistakes.

Comment: Apart from that your question is unclear. Don't explain what you think the code should look like, explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's just sketch. The idea is just sending result object to the last next instead of doing res.send + next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for a handler that executes after all other handlers in the chain are done.  Consider the "after" event handler.  In the documentation they show [an example for audit logging](http://restify.com/#audit-logging).

You should be able to use that same thing to update the response body as needed.  The code might look something like this...

```
server.on('after', function (request, response, route, error) {});
```

Keep in mind, this still requires you to `return next();` from all of the other handlers in the chain.

Comment: Nice option. Thanks!